# Can anyone identify/point me to documentation for a 6-pin SMD device marked as (W?)T2105

Tags: led-driver, reverse-engineering

I'm troubleshooting an LED workshop light that is malfunctioning and am reverse engineering a schematic to get a better sense of what may be the culprit device.  The best I can discern from viewing a 4K image of the device is that it has the markings T2105.

It appears the device drives an n-channel MOSFET (650V, 15A) to convert a rectified line voltage to about 80V DC to drive a multitude of LEDs.  I suspect the circuit performs a current limiting function to ensure LEDs aren't overdriven.

I'd appreciate any leads in identifying this part and pointing me in the direction of documentation.

[Edit-22.12.23]: Apologies for leaving out some key info.  After playing around with my camera angle and lighting, it appears there's a "W" preceding the T2105.  It's really difficult to make out. The device package is SOT-363.  Pin 1 of the device drives the gate of a TO-220 MOSFET (NCE65T260) through a 100 Ohm resistor. One WT cross-reference with a SOT-363 package (using https://smd.yooneed.one/code5754.html indicates it's triple zener diode (BZX84C30TW), while another (SMD cookbook) indicates it is a Siemens BCR48PN NPN/PNP Silicon Digital Transistor Array.  I'm still working on my schematic to see if either of these makes sense.  Any leads on other reference resources would be appreciated.

Here's a picture of the device zoomed in:[image: WT2105].

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a photo (with scale). What package is it? How do you know it's a MOSFET? How have you determined its ratings and function? If it's a SOT23 marked T2I05 (note the capital I) it matches the markings for an Infineon IRLML6246 with a 2002 date code... but that part's nowhere near your specified ratings. Please edit your question with more information!

Comment: Please add a photo of the circuit with the device. It will make it much easier to identify.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I think we can probably rule out the Zener diode -- the datasheet (https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/1057/BZX84C2V4TW_SERIES-1865975.pdf) does not match your link, with no mention of a T (and I'm not sure what a zener would be doing with its anode connected to a MOSFET gate). On the other hand, an NPN could be translating a logic level signal to a gate drive voltage, though in that case I'd expect the emitter (pin 1) to be connected to ground, and the gate on the collector side. Is pin 2 connected to a controller? What does pin 6 do?